# How do I remove this old cassette stereo? (2002 Mercedes Sprinter)

Tags: audio, dashboard, dash

I'm wanting to replace this old cassette-based stereo system. I can't see any obvious way to unhook, unscrew, dismantle or remove it.  I have the correct Haynes manual, but the instructions there cover an obviously different model of stereo.

Do I have to get underneath the dashboard or something?

[image]

Comment: Usually you'd need to remove the front facia of the dash, then it would become quite obvious how to get the stereo out. Most dashes just clip into place, but some have screws hiding in innocuous places, which can make it problematic if you don't know where to find them.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Removal of the dash it is then. I think that might be a good exercise to engage in anyway, to learn where the clips / screws are.

Comment: There is a video on youtube for a Dodge Sprinter.  The dash and stereo looks the same as yours - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUWSVkfVvvY

Comment: Before you take anything out make sure there's something you can put in. There may be adapter kits

Comment: @GdD How would I know what to put in, without seeing what the internal of housing actually looks like?